# How to get the next image stored in a database in php

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, gallery

I have initialized a variable called lets say a = 0;
when the user clicks the button for next picture, a is incremented by one and there for i need to call the picture with the id of the value of 'a'.

Would the best way to do this be to run a query every time the button is clicked, or rather store all the images in an array and call the 'a-th' value of the array on click?

Please Help, Much Appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's cons to both situations.

1. if you load all images and save to array that 1st picture might take time to load and the user might no even be interested in going to the rest.
2. if you load as they click next then it might take a while for each image loads.

when uploading images

```
    $filename = "";

            if(!empty($_FILES["file"]))
            {
                if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
                    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")))
                {
                    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
                    else
                    {
                        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                        if (file_exists("../img/noticias/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                            echo "Image " .$_FILES["file"]["name"] . " exists.";
                        else
                        {
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                            "your server path" .  $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

then save $filename to your table
To view them in gallery

```
    while($row = $db->fetch_array($query)){  
        echo '<img src="path/to/images/' . $row['filename'] . '" width="219" height="117" />';

    }
```

and using something like Lightbox you can use jquery to make a popup to view larger or add a hyperlink to each image so they can view in a seperate page the full size image.

Comment: what would be the best solution?

Comment: depending on how many images, size that you are looking at to load.  If they are decent size and not many then I would do it on load save to array, if they are pretty big then I would leave it at user will, if they want to see the next then load.  Remember for user experience have a loading gif to tell them its loading.. :)

Comment: Most galleries don't save images in databases and I don't recommend it too.

Comment: king crunch please help me :D?

Comment: @KingCrunch is right, just save the filename and path then when you load you just attach that to your <img src="rowresult" and it'll display the image found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular SQL, for example in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE [here your where-clause] LIMIT 1 OFFSET $a;
```

As a sidenote: Don't save the whole image in the database, but only the path to it.

Comment: would this be the most efficient way to do this, i could be running many queries if say there are 100 pictures = 100 queries in a short period of time?

Comment: Its not very realistic, that one can view 100 pictures in (lets say) under 1 minute (or such?), so its "efficient enough".